# Create a sqlite database to use on tests

Tags: node.js, docker, sqlite, adonis.js

I have a server implemented on Adonis.js with tests that perform operations against the main database. I want to use @Adonis.js/Vow and create a sqlite database dedicated only to use on the tests. The server is running on docker, and i use a docker-compose file to build the complete solution (3 servers and 2 other databases on postgreSQL). How can i create a sqlite database on docker to run it and connect to it on my tests?

Comment: SQLite runs in-process; it doesn't have a separate container like larger relational databases, and it doesn't have a network interface.  Whatever test setup you use to run the same tests in a non-container environment should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Like always, the first step is to install the package from npm by running the following command.

```
npm i @adonisjs/lucid@alpha
```

Once done, run the following command to set up the package.

```
node ace invoke @adonisjs/lucid
```

1.You can choose sqlite of the available databases.

2. Right after the setup command is completed, we need to copy the code for validating the environment variables to the env.ts file. Since environment variables are injected from the outside, AdonisJS recommends you validate them and ensure that your app is always running with the correct set of configuration values.
3. The config/database.ts file holds all the configuration related to the database.
4. Finally, the config file relies on the environment variables and you can update them inside the .env file.

   PG_HOST=localhost
   PG_PORT=5432
   PG_USER=root
   PG_PASSWORD=
   PG_DB_NAME=tests

**learn more**

[database introduction](https://legacy.adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/database)